# In SSIS, how to get SAP ASE OLE DB Provider to work with statements that combine parameters with 'group by'

Tags: sql, ssis, visual-studio-2005, sap-ase, oledbconnection

We have migrated from Microsoft SQL Server to Sybase ASE 15.7 and I'm currently in the process of modifying our SSIS packages to work with the new database. I've created a new 'SAP ASE OLE DB Provider' connection to replace the current 'Native OLE DB\SQL Native Client' connection which points to our new database and I'm modifying the OLE DB datasources to use this new connection. I've had to tweak some of the SQL statements slightly in some of the datasources in order to make them work (Mainly just prefixing the table names with SAPSR3. is sufficient to get the datasource working) but I've encountered an issue with one that I've been unable to resolve.

The original select statement, that used to work using the old connection, is as follows.

```
select b.REQUEST_ID,b.SEQUENCE,b.CALC_TYPE,b.PRICE,b.REQUESTER,
min(a.MATNR) as MATNR,left(a.DELTA,8) as 'DELTA',null as 'PRPRODHR'
from ZPRICE_MODEL_LOG a JOIN ZPRICE_CALC_LOG b
    on a.RESPONSE_ID = b.REQUEST_ID
where a.DELTA >= ?
and a.ACTIVE = 'X'
and a.MANDT  ='900'
group by b.REQUEST_ID,b.SEQUENCE,b.CALC_TYPE,b.PRICE,b.REQUESTER,left(a.DELTA,8)
```

However, after it seems that the SAP ASE connection has an issue with a statement that has both a parameter in combination with 'Group By'. I've had no problems with parameters in statements without a 'group by' and, likewise, I've been able to use 'group by' without a parameter in other statements.

Once I've tweaked it for our new database, If I replace the parameter with a hard coded value, as below, then this works fine and returns data.

```
SELECT   b.REQUEST_ID, b.SEQUENCE, b.CALC_TYPE, b.PRICE, b.REQUESTER, min(a.MATNR) as MATNR, left(a.DELTA,8) as DELTA, null as PRPRODHR
FROM     SAPSR3.ZPRICE_MODEL_LOG a, SAPSR3.ZPRICE_CALC_LOG b
WHERE    a.RESPONSE_ID = b.REQUEST_ID AND (a.DELTA >= 20141001000000) AND (a.ACTIVE = 'X') AND (a.MANDT = '900')
GROUP BY b.REQUEST_ID, b.SEQUENCE, b.CALC_TYPE, b.PRICE, b.REQUESTER, left(a.DELTA,8)
```

However, the exact same statement with the parameter fails.

```
SELECT   b.REQUEST_ID, b.SEQUENCE, b.CALC_TYPE, b.PRICE, b.REQUESTER, min(a.MATNR) as MATNR, left(a.DELTA,8) as DELTA, null as PRPRODHR
FROM     SAPSR3.ZPRICE_MODEL_LOG a, SAPSR3.ZPRICE_CALC_LOG b
WHERE    a.RESPONSE_ID = b.REQUEST_ID AND (a.DELTA >= ? ) AND (a.ACTIVE = 'X') AND (a.MANDT = '900')
GROUP BY b.REQUEST_ID, b.SEQUENCE, b.CALC_TYPE, b.PRICE, b.REQUESTER, left(a.DELTA,8)
```

The Error Message is as follows.

### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio

Error at Calc Log Step [ECC CALC_LOG [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E10.

Error at Calc Log Step [ECC CALC_LOG [1]]: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020204A (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

---

The error suggests that it cannot locate the tables in the source database but of course it can locate them just fine when I hard code a value instead of using a parameter. I'm unsure if this issue is with the Sybase data provider or if I've missed something in the configuration that only affects these combinations of parameters with 'group by' statements in sql statements but any pointers or workarounds that anyone can suggest would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming you are using an OLEDB source, if so how are you passing the parameter in? I would instead use a variable to hold the SQL which you could construct using expressions and then use the SQL Command from Variable option in the data access mode for the OLEDB source.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is an OLE DB Source. The parameter is placed in a variable by an 'Execute SQL' task that runs earlier in the control flow. The value originates from another OLE DB connection, this time to an MS SQL database. I can have a go at constructing the SQL for this OLEDB source earlier in the chain, placing it in a variable and then using the SQL command from variable. I presume this will still result in the same SQL being  passed over the connection, however, the only difference being in the way the statement is constructed so it will be interesting to see if this makes any difference.

Comment: What is the data type of the `DELTA` column in the database, the data type of your variable, and the data type you declared for the OLEDB parameter? In the condition of your statement, you compare the column to a number, but you also apply `left` to it which is a function defined on character data types.

Comment: The DELTA column is a decimal in the database which is the same as it was on the old database. The variable is stored as a string.

Comment: I guess the `left` must work due to some implicit conversion going on. Perhaps the native OLE provider is also able to implicitly convert the parameter back to a decimal but the Sybase provider is not?

Comment: hmm, maybe not then, tried casting it as below but still the same result...
`SELECT   b.REQUEST_ID, b.SEQUENCE, b.CALC_TYPE, b.PRICE, b.REQUESTER, min(a.MATNR) as MATNR, left(a.DELTA,8) as DELTA, null as PRPRODHR
FROM     SAPSR3.ZPRICE_MODEL_LOG a, SAPSR3.ZPRICE_CALC_LOG b
WHERE    a.RESPONSE_ID = b.REQUEST_ID AND (a.DELTA >= CONVERT(DECIMAL(15), ?) AND (a.ACTIVE = 'X') AND (a.MANDT = '900')
GROUP BY b.REQUEST_ID, b.SEQUENCE, b.CALC_TYPE, b.PRICE, b.REQUESTER, left(a.DELTA,8)`

Comment: Ok, I've got a bodge workaround for my problem which will means I can move on for now. Its not really a solution but I found that the string parameter originates from a value which is, to all intents and purposes, constant as it just points to a particular date on which the original delta was run. For now, I've just hardcoded that value into the select to avoid this issue occurring. I just don't have the time to faff around with it any more, unfortunately!
Thanks for all your help :)